# Effective heroku debugging strategies and tools

Tags: debugging, heroku

What is the correct approach when debugging errors on Heroku cloud? Logs are very useful but some errors are realy hard to debug, since messages in logs are often not sufficient to be able to understand nature of the problem. So I wonder what is your approach in general, especially for problems that are hard to reproduce, e.g. when error happens non-deterministically or when error seems to happen somewhere else than in your code. What tools and strategies do you use on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

Some errors on Heroku don't provide an error traceback. Furthermore if you have a project where you allow other people to deploy your code you don't get their error logs unless they share them to you.

In those scenarios [sentry.io](https://sentry.io/platforms/) is pretty nice. (If you are allowing others to use your code a disclaimer would be nice that data are gathered or better allow them to enable/disable the service.)

With that it would also really help if you do extensive logging in your application. Try to handle a variety of errors. Allow your logs to be filtered by info, warning and error as well as the file it was called in.

And for software development in general maintaining tests is crucial. It's easy to run your test with changed parameters. You get failed tests and immediately know why things went wrong.

Try to have a strong CI pipeline before deploying your project to Heroku and you will have to do less fixes while you are on production.